# new bash does no more accept FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc'

Tags: bash

All the years I have set

```
export FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc'
```

After a crash of bash due to typos, a new instance of bash was invoked.

This is in KDE under Konsole by opening a new window for a TERMINAL.

After having set up FCEDIT with the code shown, command "fc" gives the error

bash: vim -u /root/.vimrc: No such file or directory.

With vim alone without option -u, fc does work after setting up by

```
FCEDIT='vim'
```

Why, what has happened with bash?

I tried a wayaround:

```
export FCEDIT=WEfunc_fcedi1; WEfunc_fcedi1(){ vim -u /root/.vimrc; }
```

With this set up, fc gives no error.

But "fc" does not work as usual: The last command in the command lines of bash is not taken up to be edited, but vim is invoked as standalone without any input.

Regards == 01.02.2023 01:53

Comment: Meta note: please stop littering your posts, edits and comments with timestamps. The site itself tracks these and does it better. Better, because these timestamps are explicitly in Zulu time, while your timestamps may be in any timezone and thus they are useless until one compares them to the information provided by the site anyway.

Comment: (1) `export FCEDIT='vim -u /root/.vimrc'` works for me in Bash 5.2.2. What is the output of `bash --version` in your case? (2) My tests indicate `FCEDIT` gets split according to the current `IFS`. Do you use a nonstandard value for `IFS`? `IFS` without a space in an interactive shell seems weird, `fc` in a script seems weird, so they should never meet. But (judging by your previous posts) your workflow is sometimes surprising *for me*, so all bets are off, I think. :) (3) If the standard `IFS`, please make sure the `FCEDIT` you actually use contains ASCII spaces: `printf %s "$FCEDIT" | od -c`